# How to show/hide a View in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I want a View to be hidden on load, then when a user clicks on a link it will display the view. Can someone review my code and let me know what I have done wrong?

```
App.parentView = Em.View.extend({   
  click: function() {
    App.childView.set('isVisible', true);
  }
});

App.childView = Em.View.extend({
  isVisible: false
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/uxyrw/5/

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with your actual code? The block you pasted seems incomplete.

Comment: Without seeing the templates, i.e. how the Views are being put on the page, this is impossible to debug. My suggestion would be adding some `Em.Logger.log` statements in the `click` function (to ensure it's actually being called) and actually put something in the views so they aren't just empty divs. Try editing this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/uxyrw/4/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would create a simple `isVisibleBinding` to the view you want to hide/show, see 
http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/dTV6q/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.ParentView}}
        <h1>Parent</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="#" {{action "toggle"}}>hide/show</a>
        </div>     
        {{#view App.ChildView isVisibleBinding="isChildVisible" }}
            {{view Em.TextArea rows="2" cols="20"}}
        {{/view}}        
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.ParentView = Em.View.extend({   
    isChildVisible: true,

    toggle: function(){
        this.toggleProperty('isChildVisible');
    }
});

App.ChildView = Ember.View.extend();
```

---

A note about your naming conventions: classes should be named `UpperCase` and instances `lowerCase`. See [blog post](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html) about this.

​

Comment: Thanks for your help Pangratz, another quick question. If the childView was in an {{each}} and it generated many more childViews, how would i target the show/hide toggle to the specific one selected?

Comment: I would create a `CollectionView` which' `itemViewClass` handles the toggling of visibility. See http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/ZTdPF/.

Answer (score -1):

Valuebinding for some reasons didnt work for me so observing parentView property inside childView did the trick for me

Handlebar:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.ParentView}}
        <h1>Parent</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="#" {{action "toggle"}}>hide/show</a>
        </div>     
        {{#view App.ChildView }}
            {{view Em.TextArea rows="2" cols="20"}}
        {{/view}}        
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

Coffeescript:

```
App.ParentView = Em.View.extend
  isChildVisible: true
  toggle: ->
    @toggleProperty 'isChildVisible'
App.ChildView = Em.View.extend
  isVisible: (->
    @get('parentView.isChildVisible')
  ).property '_parentView.isChildVisible'
```